# Why won't my search box return any results?

Tags: asp.net

I am Using asp.net mvc5 and trying to add a textbox above my table to search for items in the table. In my view I have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <p>
       Find by Start/End Point @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
       <input type="submit" value="Search" />
   </p>
}
```

Then In my controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
    var lift = from l in db.Lifts select l;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        lift = lift.Where(l => l.StartPoint.Contains(searchString)
                                || l.EndPoint.Contains(searchString));
    }
        return View(lifts.ToList());
    }
}
```

However it returns the same table every time. It is probably something silly I am doing wrong but I can't see.

Comment: Did you try with a break point in your controller and check for every different `searchString` you are getting expected results from `db`?

Comment: have you checked with break point? is your code hitting the controller?

Comment: Did you try breakpoint check. Searchstring needs to have a valid value.

Comment: In these scenarios, debugging using break points are very much helpful as @SivaGopal mentioned. try that out.

Comment: it seems that the value of searchString is null or empty every time. Also change the searchString to SearchString in your controller.

Comment: I have added break points and the value does seem to be passed through

Comment: so what are you getting in `SearchString`?

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","ControllerName",new { sortOrder = "Desc/Asc" },FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <p>
                        Find by Start/End Point @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
                            <input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
                    }
```

Action code:-

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string SearchString)
        {
            var lift = from l in db.Lifts select l;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
            {
                lift = lift.Where(l => l.StartPoint.Contains(SearchString)
                                       || l.EndPoint.Contains(SearchString));
            }
             return View(lifts.ToList());
            }
        }
```

Comment: change `ControllerName` with your Actual Controller name and Pass `Desc` or `Asc` in `sortOrder`

Comment: Should the "searchString" in the controller start with a capital S or small s?

Comment: it'll be capital S

Comment: Unfortunately this does the same thing

Comment: did you try using breakpoint? are you getting value in SearchString in action

Comment: @DavidRegan I have edited my answer , kindly try it now